# SQL not yielding expected results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables related to this particular query:

- Lawson_Employees: `LawsonID` (pk), `LastName`, `FirstName`, `AccCode` (numeric)
- Lawson_DeptInfo: `AccCode` (pk), `AccCode2` (don't ask, HR set up), `DisplayName`
- tblExpirationDates: `EmpID` (pk), `ACLS` (date), `EP` (date), `CPR` (date), `CPR_Imported` (date), `PALS` (date), `Note`

The goal is to get the data I need to report on all those who have already expired in one or more certification, or are going to expire in the next 90 days.

Some important notes:

- This is being run as part of a vbScript, so the 90-day date is being calculated when the script is run. I'm using `2010-08-31` as a placeholder since its the result at the time this question is being posted.
- All cards expire at the end of the month. (which is why the above date is for the end of August and not 90 days on the dot)
- A valid EP card supersedes ACLS certification, but only the latter is required of some employees. (wasn't going to worry about it until I got this question answered, but if I can get the help I'll take it)
- The CPR column contains the expiration date for the last class they took with us. (NULL if they didn't take any classes with us)
- The CPR_Imported column contains the expiration date for the last class they took somewhere else. (NULL if they didn't take it elsewhere, and bravo for following policy)
- The distinction between CPR classes is important for other reports. For purposes of this report, all we really care about is which one is the most current - or at least is currently current.
- If I have to, I'll ignore ACLS and PALS for the time being as it is non-compliance with CPR training that is the big issue at the moment. (not that the others won't be, but they weren't mentioned in the last meeting...)

Here's the query I have so far, which is giving me good data:

```
SELECT 
    iEmp.LawsonID, iEmp.LastName, iEmp.FirstName, 
    dept.AccCode2, dept.DisplayName, 
    Exp.ACLS, Exp.EP, Exp.CPR, Exp.CPR_Imported, Exp.PALS, Exp.Note 
FROM (Lawson_Employees AS iEmp 
        LEFT JOIN Lawson_DeptInfo AS dept ON dept.AccCode = iEmp.AccCode) 
        LEFT JOIN tblExpirationDates AS Exp ON iEmp.LawsonID = Exp.EmpID 
WHERE iEmp.CurrentEmp = 1 
    AND ((Exp.ACLS <= #2010-08-31# 
            AND Exp.ACLS IS NOT NULL)
        OR (Exp.CPR <= #2010-08-31# 
            AND Exp.CPR_Imported <= #2010-08-31#) 
        OR (Exp.PALS <= #2010-08-31# 
            AND Exp.PALS IS NOT NULL))
ORDER BY dept.AccCode2, iEmp.LastName, iEmp.FirstName;
```

After perusing the result set, I think I'm missing some expiration dates that should be in the result set. Am I missing something? This is the sucky part of being the only developer in the department... no one to ask for a little help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
 OR (Exp.CPR <= #2010-08-31# 
            AND Exp.CPR_Imported <= #2010-08-31#)
```

Null is not less than or greater than anything.

If you need the people who do not have a valid CPR, you will need to include nulls.

It may be easiest to use Nz:

```
 OR (Nz(Exp.CPR,#2010-08-31#) <= #2010-08-31# 
            AND Nz(Exp.CPR_Imported,#2010-08-31#) <= #2010-08-31#)
```

Comment: There is actually no need to use Nz() for this, and I'd recommend avoiding unnecessary function calls.

Comment: So what do you recommend? It would appear from the OP that data is not returned, it is likely that this is because nulls are being excluded. It is by far the easiest thing to use Nz. And I see no point in voting up a generalized comment when this may well be the exception unless an alternative solution is offered.

Comment: @Remount, I am getting results back. They just look incomplete. We had a network outage Friday, so I won't be able to test the answers until Tuesday (office is closed Monday for the holiday)

Comment: @Remou: I would test for the data value OR is null, rather than using Nz(). My approach is more portable, for one, but also more efficient (it uses indexes).

Comment: That is quite a long statement in that an OR and AND is already needed for this one part a longer WHERE statement. As I said, Nz is going to be a lot easier.

Comment: Furthermore, I note in your other comment that you do not like the use of `Or Is Null`, either.

Comment: Huh? I'm recommending Or Is Null explicitly as the way to code it to show matches to the desired values and the ones without any value. Other than Nz(), it's the only way to do it. And I suspect it's going to be optimized much more efficiently, as well. I can't fathom why you'd worry about a "long" WHERE clause. This isn't even what I'd consider a long one!

Comment: I worry about long where statements when someone is still trying to get the whole thing working, they are hard to read if you are not very familiar with SQL, especially when it is not possible to maintain a nice layout in the query design window. The above is only a snippet from the original and is the part that I believe is leaving the OP short on expected data. I suggest going with the easier version and getting it working before worrying about speed. I   will look for a quote from you on these lines and on this site that I recall.